# Client-side http connections in webpage without domain restriction

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to make a webpage where the user browser would have to download data like with Ajax but without domain restrictions. I don't care about the technology. Flash, Java, whatever. Is it possible?

Comment: Domain restrictions are there for a purpose. What do you think would happen if browsers would allow loading data from everywhere?

Comment: So, it's impossible in every technology?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have control of the other servers and [access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) is not an option, one common way is to have a proxy on your own server. Can be as simple as a PHP script

```
$handle = fopen($_GET['url'], "rb");
while ( !feof($handle) ) {
    echo fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
```

that is used in `proxy.php?url=http://example.com/data/` fashion.

Comment: No, I want the clients to download it so the server doesn't have to.

Comment: As halfdan noted, the restrictions are there for a reason. By using a proxy, the requests to the external server will be coming from your server, making it easy to block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

When fetching data with ajax, the domain doesn't matter because it's simply an independent http-request. It's as if you would be typing the url in a new browser tab, but in the case of ajax, your browser handles these requests automatically.

This is similar to what happens to images, scripts, css files, ...

(I use php5 and jquery for my apps)

Comment: I believe you are wrong since cross domain policy applies to http requests